# Explicit expressions for "weakly holomorphic" modular forms of weight 1

Tags: modular-forms

I am mainly thinking about the group $\Gamma(N)$. A weakly modular form of weight one is a holomorphic function $f: \mathfrak{H} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying
$$
f(\gamma \tau) = (c\tau+d)f(\tau), \qquad \gamma \in \Gamma(N),
$$
and which is also "meromorphic at the cusps". It corresponds to an algebraic section of the Hodge line bundle $\underline{\omega}$ over $Y(N) = \mathfrak{H}/\Gamma(N)$.

I believe that, at least for small values of $N$, the Hodge line bundle is actually trivial (in other words, the universal elliptic curve over $Y(N)$ admits a Weierstrass equation). In particular, the trivialization of the $\underline{\omega}$ should correspond to some explicit weakly modular form of weight 1 with no zeros.

Where can I find explicit formulas for such modular forms? For instance, can they be defined by a series on $\mathfrak{H}$ (much like Eisenstein or Poincaré series)?

Comment: Y(N) is affine, so the Hodge bundle is trivial automatically (modulo stackiness issues for N = 1 or 2 which mean the bundle doesn't exist)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Is this a particular property of the Hodge bundle? I don't think it's true in general that every line bundle over an affine curve is trivial (algebraically).

Comment: Oops, that was wrong, sorry. Here is a fix. There is a construction of Tate giving a moduli space for pairs $(E, P)$, over an arbitrary base scheme, such that $P$ does *not* have order 1, 2 or 3. Over this space the universal elliptic curve has a Weierstrass equation. So we can pull back this universal Weierstrass equation to any modular curve.

Comment: For the construction of Tate I referred to, see $\S9$ of these seminar notes: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/vigregroup/vigre03/moduli.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing David's answer, it is clear that any eta quotient of level $N$ and weight 1 satisfies the required condition. If you ask in addition that the
form be holomorphic, it is not difficult to write a program giving all holomorphic eta quotients of a given level. For instance there are none in prime level
$N\equiv1\pmod4$ (and more generally 50 levels out of the first 100 have none), but otherwise some levels have hundreds. The smallest level is of course level $4$ with
the eta quotient $\eta(\tau)^{-4}\eta(2\tau)^{10}\eta(4\tau)^{-4}=\theta(\tau)^2$.

This begs for instance the additional question: do there exist weakly modular forms of weight $1$ and level $N\equiv1\pmod4$ prime? I assume this is known.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wary of speaking about "***the*** trivialisation of $\omega$", since the unit group $\mathcal{O}(Y(N))^\times$ (the group of modular units) is a pretty big group, and your trivialization will only be well-defined up to a modular unit, so there is no reason to expect any particularly canonical choice.

That said, for certain explicit $N$ you can find one. For $N = 23$, there is a holomorphic cusp form of weight 1 which vanishes nowhere on $\mathcal{H}$, given by the rather elegant formula $q \prod_{n \ge 1} (1 - q^n)(1 - q^{23n})$ where $q = e^{2\pi i z}$ as usual. (That is, this form is just $\eta(z) \eta(23z)$ where $\eta$ is Dedekind's eta function.) Note the non-vanishing is obvious from the convergence of the infinite product.

I don't know of straightforward examples for general values of $N$; probably one wants to look for products, rather than sums. Maybe the theory of *Borcherds products* might be of use here, but I'm not an expert on that theory so I'll leave it to others to comment on that.